# Sketch and determine area of region w

Tags: calculus, area, polar-coordinates

No clue on how to approach this problem, this info is all that's given:
$$2\leq r \leq 3+2\cos(\phi)$$

Assignment is to sketch the region W and determine the area of this region. It is given in polar coordinates. What I've done so far is set $2$ equal to $3+2\cos(\phi)$, returning a value of $\phi=2\pi/3$. How do I continue from this point?

Comment: In words, your region is the space inside the cardioid $r=3+\cos(\phi)$ and outside the circle $r=2$.

Comment: You should double-check the value of $\phi$ at the point of intersection.

Comment: And you should review the process of finding the area of a region bounded by a polar curve and two polar rays. The procedure is straight-forward and, in this case, results in elementary integrals. Have you studied the material upon which this problem is based?

Comment: The values of $\phi$ are indeed sloppy, it was meant to be $\pm 2\pi/3$.

I've done some more research and I've ended up with following formula, would this give the correct answer once worked out? (I have no answers for my practice questions, so can't check).

$$\int^{2\pi/3}_{-2\pi/3}\int^{3+cos(\phi)}_{2}rdrd\phi$$

Comment: Since when is either $\cos \frac{2\pi}3$ or $\cos \frac{2\pi}3$ equal to $-1$?

Comment: I wrote the question entirely wrong I found, it was supposed to be $3+2\cos(\phi)$. My bad!